# How to search for 2 different parameters in dart list?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to search for 2 different parameters in a dart list?
Is there a simple method?

Can I solve the problem using `contains`?

```dart
void _runFilter(String searchKeyword) {
    List<Product> results = [];

    if (searchKeyword.isEmpty) {
      results = allProducts;
    } else {
      results = allProducts.where(
            (element) => 
                element.name.toLowerCase().contains(searchKeyword.toLowerCase()) || element.image.toLowerCase().contains(searchKeyword.toLowerCase()),
                  
                ),
          )
          .toList();
      results = results +
          allProducts
              .where(
                (element) => element.image.toLowerCase().contains(
                      searchKeyword.toLowerCase(),
                    ),
              )
              .toList();
    }

    // refresh the UI
    setState(() {
      filteredProducts = results;
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you include a sample of list and the expected result to be returned ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write all sorts of if-else-combinations in a closure. If you use the `{}` notation instead of `=>` it will become clearer. Something like this will accomplish what you are looking for:

```
results = allProducts.where( (element) {
            if ( element.name.toLowerCase().contains(searchKeyword.toLowerCase()) {
              return true;
            } else if ( element.image.toLowerCase().contains(searchKeyword.toLowerCase()) {
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          }).toList();
```

If this step is clear, you can then try to combine individual statements into a boolean combination via `||` or `&&` if this looks more convenient in your code.